# Mesh wifi setups: Do the ethernet ports support printers?

Tags: wireless-networking

I am setting up a mesh wifi setup in my house.

One of the needs is to hang a laser printer off one of the mesh nodes. (You know, give the printer an IP address, allow LPR/LPD printing over the mesh network.)

Is that a thing?

What features do I need to look for in mesh hardware to support this? (Other than the physical ethernet port, of course!)

Comment: Why do you want to "mesh wifi" in your house? Meshing decrease wlan throughput.

Answer (score 0):

I added a Ubiquity Hotspot in my home (Mesh not needed for a normal home) and I ensured that all my equipment is on one subnet. Printing anywhere from any device including phones works a treat.  Just ensure one subnet and, yes, give the printer a static IP address on your network to ensure it does not get lost on restarts. Ethernet printer and Ethernet / Wireless devices all supported